# Can you get a list of the powers in a polynomial? Pari GP

Tags: polynomials, pari, pari-gp

I'm working with single variable polynomials with coefficients +1/-1 (and zero). These can be very long and the range of powers can be quite big. It would be convenient for me to view the powers as a vector - is there any way of doing this quickly? I had hoped there would be a command already in Pari to do this, but I can't seem to see one?

Just an example to confirm what I'm trying to do...

Input:`x^10 - x^8 + x^5 - x^2 + x + 1`

Desired output: `[10, 8, 5, 2, 1, 0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Vecrev` to get the polynomial coefficients. After that just enumerate them to select the zero-based positions of non-zeros. You want the following one-liner:

```
nonzeros(xs) = Vecrev([x[2]-1 | x <- select(x -> x[1] != 0, vector(#xs, i, [xs[i], i]))])
```

Now you can easily get the list of polynomial powers:

```
p = x^10 - x^8 + x^5 - x^2 + x + 1
nonzeros(Vecrev(p))
>> [10, 8, 5, 2, 1, 0]
```